# Unmanaged Code debugging Visual Studio 2012 ErrorCode CXX0017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vb6

I want to debug unmanaged Code in Visual Studio 2012. The unmanaged code is based on VB6. It's possible to step through the code. But the value of many variables coudln't be accessed. I receive the errorcoe CXX0017 by Visual Studio 2012. For example I would like to debug a MSXML variable. I don't have a pdb / symbol files of these variables.

What can I do the see the value of the variable?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the pdb / symbol files you will NOT be able to debug through them.

Comment: In the Visual Studio 6 I don't get these errors. I already searched for the pdb on my harddisk, but I couldn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a clean/rebuild as the user (with the problem) should help fix it or give you more clues as to what's causing it (like a permissions issue).